# crispy_forms is not working : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'crispy_forms'

Tags: python, django, django-crispy-forms

Steps that I followed

1. pip install django-crispy-forms
2. add inside setting.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'crispy_forms',
    ...
]
```

and

```
CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'uni_form'
```

3. press the run icon of pycharm (top right)

I tried to install

> ```
> pip install -e git+git://github.com/maraujop/django-crispy-forms.git#egg=django-crispy-forms
> ```

I tried to make a migration but same error.
I tried to install with pipenv install django-crispy-forms.

I don't have the error if I do :
"python3 manage.py runserver"
but crispy-forms doesn't work

ERROR :

```
...
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1004, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'crispy_forms'
```

Comment: It sounds like the python version Pycharm is using is different from the one that you have pip installed from. What is the output of `which pip` and `which python` ?

Comment: HI. when I do pip3 install django-crispy-forms I have : Requirement already satisfied: django-crispy-forms in c:\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages (1.14.0)

Comment: I found à solution using "python3 manage.py runserver" But I don't think it's sustainable, and without setting up a local server, it won't work anymore.

Comment: currently I can't DEBUG with pycharm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution, when you install **crispy_form** with `pip3 install django-crispy-forms`

It works and it does the installation well but not in the right place.
The installation is done in the Python directory of the computer.

> pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages

**But** With PyCharm, I use a **venv** where I store all the configuration.

**It is necessary to retrieve the files installed in the Python directory (in my case **crispy_forms**) and drag them into the `venv/(app name)/lib/site-packages`.**